# How to specify correct version of a python module

Tags: python, scapy

I have a container with two versions of scapy python modules installed. One `2.2.0-dev` installed from sources by this [project](https://github.com/p4lang/scapy-vxlan) that I install. It comes with `2.2.0-dev` bundled with it. I'm trying to figure out if skipping its installation would break anything.

Also, I use pip and install scapy (`pip2 install scapy`)

This results in having `2.4.3` installed.

Now when I have this sample script `s.py` written as shown below, it seems to load from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/ where the VERSION file says `2.4.3` but later when I call `interact()` it says version `2.2.0-dev`. Is there a proper way I can force import of the `2.4.3` modules?

```
$ cat s.py
import scapy
print(scapy)
print(scapy.__file__)

from scapy.main import interact
interact()

$ python s.py
<module 'scapy' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/__init__.pyc'>
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/__init__.pyc

INFO: Can't import python gnuplot wrapper . Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
INFO: Can't import python Crypto lib. Won't be able to decrypt WEP.
INFO: Can't import python Crypto lib. Disabled certificate manipulation tools
Welcome to Scapy (2.2.0-dev)
>>>

$ cat /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/VERSION
2.4.3
```

Comment: Side remark: You should not be developing new code for Python 2.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I'm aware of that. I had to, to just go along with the old modules that were on 2.7